# Sending SIGTERM to all processes

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I have a bash script call `run.sh` that launches multiple processes

```
#!/bin/bash
proc1 &
proc2 &
proc3 &
final # this runs until sigterm
```

When I execute `run.sh` and I send a SIGTERM to run.sh, I don't think SIGTERM is being sent to `final`, and I don't think it is being sent to `proc1`, `proc2`, and `proc3`. Note that in this use case this is a docker container which runs `run.sh`, and running `docker stop` is the way I'm trying to send SIGTERM.

What would be the easiest way for the bash script to send a sigterm to all of the processes it started? The only way I can think of is by starting `final` with the `&` too and then do a while loop in `run.sh`?

EDIT - I've tried it though, doesn't seem to work:
In `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
_term() { 
  echo "Caught SIGTERM signal!" 
}
trap _term SIGTERM
echo "hi"
sleep 100000 &
wait $!
```

When running docker stop, I never see `Caught SIGTERM signal!`

Comment: You need to pass down the `_term` function name as a string like: `trap '_term' SIGINT`

Comment: @h3nrik I tried '_term', still not working

Comment: Your script can't run the handler until after `sleep` exits, since it isn't interrupted. Run it in the background with `sleep 100000 &`; then the `wait` command is executed and *can* be interrupted to run your hander. Incidentally, `$!` isn't well-defined in your script because you haven't run any background commands yet.

Comment: @h3nrik `_term` *is* a string. The quotes just protect any special characters from shell interpretation; they don't define a string.

Comment: @chepner i modified the code. it still doesn't output Caught SIGTERM signal

Comment: Either you aren't sending `SIGTERM` (`kill -TERM`), or it's a Docker-related issue as described by h3nrik.

Answer (score 1):

You said you run that script in a Docker container. Could you give us more details on how your start the container and how the `run.sh` is invoked?.

When `docker stop` is invoked or a direct `SIGTERM` is received by the container the contained process with PID 1 will receive it. When your `run.sh` creates child processes that run in background **it also has to forward signals to them**.

Therefore it is not a good approach to create background child processes in a bash script with `&`. Using a [supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) would be a good practice as it handles signals properly and forwards them to its child processes without any further scripting needed.

In addition the `supervisord` should not be started as a shell child process itself. That would happen if you specify this as your container command in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord
```

Instead it should look like:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

That way the supervisor becomes the root process with PID 1 and will receive all the signals properly and redirects them to its child processes.

Comment: So my run.sh is the CMD that runs for the docker container. But I'm confused - why wouldn't trapping the signals with bash on run.sh work (and fyi, i just tried and it doens't)

Comment: Because you would explicitly need to use `trap`s as described [here](http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html) for instance.

Comment: Also I've verified that my run.sh starts on PID 1

Comment: I would not spend much time on getting that script working. It is generally a bad practice in the Docker context and quite tricky to get running as you just experienced. Either use only one process per container or use the supervisor as described.

Comment: But look at my latest example. Shouldn't that be working?

Comment: [chepner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)s solution works well. But still not recommendable in a Docker environment.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Docker, so I will defer to h3nrik here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jobs -p` to get the process ids of any background jobs, then pass them to `kill`.

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' TERM

proc1 &
proc2 &
proc3 &

wait
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct, I would collect them all in an array and then send a signal to each one of them when finished. I would use something like `awk '{ system("kill -15 " $1)}'`.

Comment: Do *not* use `kill -9`. That's for killing buggy programs, as it doesn't allow the process to clean up after itself.

Comment: Correct in this context, sigterm or sigint is probably more appropriate.  Unless of course they are not well behaved processes, then sigkill is the ticket...since it cannot be ignored.